# mongoose limit render issues

Tags: express, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to implement infinite scroll in EJS and am trying to first render database items but limit it only to 1. So I made a test page in ejs, and was able to render the first item in the database in plaintext.

**express/mongoose serverside:**

```
app.get("/test",(req,res)=>{
  database.find({}, (err, found) => {
    if (!err){
      res.render("test",{
        db           :found,
        logStatus    :true,
      });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }).limit(1);
});
```

**EJS:**

```
<boilerplate code for header and navbar>

<p><%=db%></p>

<boilerplate code for footer>
```

this part worked so I tried next to load the database contents individually:

**express/mongoose serverside:**

```
app.get("/test",(req,res)=>{  
  database.find({}, (err, found) => {
    if (!err){
      res.render("test",{
        db           :found,
        link         :found.link,
        name         :found.name,
        price        :found.price,
        logStatus    :true,
      });
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }).limit(1);
});
```

**EJS side**

```
<boilerplate code for header and navbar>

<p><%=link%></p>

<boilerplate code for footer>
```

this doesn't render anything so I am at a complete loss as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find()` method return an array of documents so `found` is an array and you can not call `.link` on it. You can change it to `found[0].link` or use `findOne()` method instead.

Comment: You can loop through `found` array and display each item of it in your ejs file.

Comment: so you're saying I am returning only found right now? I hope to play with the limit size in a bit to show hopefully the first dozen items.

Comment: Okay fantastic! Looks like I was overthinking the syntax as usual. I thought I would have to tweak the syntax way more than I  should.

Comment: alright so I actually had my home page do a forEach loop from the get go on the home page. Another dev introduced me to socket IO and I am using that to handle requests for now. I am now trying to render the items in question on the page. I was thinking I could try pushing the contents somehow into my ejs render or if I should try something else.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand what "items in question" is.

Comment: My apologies. I am now at the stage where I have the db contents loading up to the first several db items (the res.renders). Now in order load the additional items from the database My idea was to run a get request and somehow push the requested contents into found. I have a mockup written in another thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58828185/infinite-scrolling-in-ejs