# infinite scrolling in EJS

Tags: socket.io, ejs, infinite-scroll

As the title says I am trying to implement infinite scroll on my page using ejs.

Right now I have it set to render a finite number of items from my database to the page.

**Express JS side:**

```
app.get(`/`, (req, res) => {
    database.find({}, (err, items) => {
      if (!err){
        res.render("home",{cards:items});  
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }).limit(20);
});
```

On the the EJS side I have the items then displayed in EJS by means of a forEach loop.

```
<%cards.forEach((i) => {%>

  <p><%=i.contents%></p>

<%})%>
```

Which loads the finite number of resources.

Now using Socket io, I'm able to send a request for additional content

**Client**

```
socket.emit("loadmore", parseInt(count));
```

**server**

```
socket.on("loadmore", (count) => {
  linkscr.amazon.find({},(e,found)=>{
    if(!e){
      const data = found;
      socket.emit("loadmore", data);
    }
  }).skip(count).limit(10);

});
```

Now I have another ten items I want to try to push into the running for loop, but as far as I know, I can not see how to do so as I am running the function in  for the request function. Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: Look like you don't need to use socket in this case, an api will be enough. And after you get the response, use js or jquery to append to the list.

Comment: how would I append to the list? That's my underlining problem. I see no way of adding fetched data from client js to the rendered server js data.

Comment: So i rewrote everything and now I am stuck trying to insert the html. I have it written in another thread, and I am so frustratingly close to solving this.